# character control in backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using backbone js on the client side with Spring MVC on the server side. 
What I need is basically to have a filter whenever a server call is made from backbone to filter out characters which are banned from security point of view - in the post or get request.

I can write a function which is called before I post / call the server side but what I would love to see if there is a generic way to do it. Can I write a piece of code which filters out / replaces those characters before every server call.

Comment: For security reasons, you should filter those characters on the server side anyway. Because anybody can send a request directly to your API, thus circumventing your backbone filter.

Comment: There is already a reverse proxy set up at server side. The idea is to block the contents at the client side to have a user friendly interface rather than reach the reverse proxy and then get it blocked.

Comment: How do you sync to the server? Do you use backbone.sync?

Comment: Because if you do, you could overwrite the backbone.sync function and filter the contents of the models that you are sending.

Comment: I use backbone sync but other functions as well.

Comment: How about you just filter the user input directly? So far, I haven't seen a general way to filter everything that goes through backbone, if you're using other methods than backbone.sync.

Comment: Ok. In that case, is it possible that I create a validator which is called generically for each form or fields inside the form etc. That way I can create a validator and use it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that it should be handled by the backend and front-end should fail pleasantly only for well intentioned users (and not for someone that is clearly attempting to do something wrong), here is your solution:

As every Backbone request is made through Backbone.sync using Backbone.ajax, just override Backbone.ajax:

```
var ajax = Backbone.ajax;

Backbone.ajax = function (options) {

    // check if options.data is an object or an string;
    var data = options.emulateJSON ? JSON.stringify(options.data) : options.data; 

    // do your sanitization here at data
    // ...

    // dont forget to sanitize your url options.url
    // ...

    options.data = options.emulateJSON ? JSON.parse(data) : data;

    // call the original method
    return ajax(options);

};
```

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Thanks. As I am new to backbone, I need some advice :
1. Is it possible that I keep this somewhere in a central place maybe in a parent view. I have a distributed web application and have many client apps. I want to reuse this across.
2. Can I provide the user with an error message on the view everytime to inform about the forbidden characters

Comment: 1. If you add this script right after the backbone, it will (by definition) work on all of your models/collections. 2. Not with the code I provided.

Please accept this as the answer.